# How to change a control style using a pseudo class like focus or pointerover in avalonia ui?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I've been searching for a way to change a control style when a pointer is over it or when it's in focus something like this

```
<Style Selector="TextBox:focus">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

but for some reason nothing is happenning or changing

instead the TextBox background stayed in the same color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By referring to the Documentation [Selector with a pseudoclass doesn't override the default](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/guides/styles-and-resources/troubleshooting#selector-with-a-pseudoclass-doesnt-override-the-default)

The corrected code should target Border by using [template selector](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/styling/selectors#template)

```xml
<Style Selector="TextBox:focus /template/ Border">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```